# Left join not work in symfony using doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, left-join

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with doctrine. I want to create query with left join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id ...
```

I did sth like this:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('*')
->from('Table1 t')
->leftJoin('Table2 t2')
...
```

I have in my schema.yml relation between Table1 and Table2

```
  relations:
    Table2:
      class:          Table2
      local:          id
      foreign:        table1_id
      onDelete:       cascade
      type:           one
      foreignType:    one
      foreignAlias:   Table1Table2
```

Finally I get query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 ...
```

There is no LEFT JOIN clause. Does anybody know why?

Comment: is the result the same if the query is SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id ?

Comment: Have you tried it ? I know that old propel version handle (sometimes) left join like that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the [`join` syntax](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#join-syntax), you should give the referent of the joined table (look in the `leftJoin`):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('Table1 t')
        ->leftJoin('t.Table2 t2')
```

Comment: According to the schema, it should be `->leftJoin('t.Table1Table2 t2')` no ?

Comment: hmm nop, the relation name is `Table2` (it's just the line after `relations:`).